# Access service's endpoint /actuator/health through Spring Cloud Netflix: Zuul

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix

I have Spring gateway: `localhost:7856` and microservice - "my-service", for example `localhost:8081`. I can get access to endpoint `localhost:8081/actuator/health` -> `{"status": "UP"}`. But I need to access such endpoint through gateway like `localhost:7856/my-service/actuator/health`
My gateway config:

```
zuul:
  ignoredServices: '*'
  routes:
    my-service:
      path: /my-service/**
      serviceId: my-service
      stripPrefix: false
```

Here, crucial moment, I can't change `stripPrefix to true`. I know, that I can add

```
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
       base-path: /my-service/actuator
```

but it wouldn't be good solution, because in that case also need to change eureka config (for eureka default endpoint is service-name/actuator/health) for check health status for microservices. Or I can create additional endpoint that would redirect to what I need. But I'm trying to find the best decision, may be its a special property for zuul or overriding zuul classes ?

Comment: Maybe try something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31829773/how-to-do-url-rewrite-in-zuul-proxy)

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found a solution.

```
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.Route;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.SimpleRouteLocator;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.ZuulProperties;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.ZuulProperties.ZuulRoute;

public class CustomRouteLocator extends SimpleRouteLocator {

    public CustomRouteLocator(String servletPath, ZuulProperties properties) {
        super(servletPath, properties);
    }

    @Override
    protected Route getRoute(ZuulRoute route, String path) {
        boolean oldPrefix = route.isStripPrefix();

        if (path.matches(".*/actuator/.*")) {
            route.setStripPrefix(true);
        }

        Route resultRoute = super.getRoute(route, path);
        route.setStripPrefix(oldPrefix);

        return resultRoute;
    }
}
```

I turn on/off stripPrefix property. That works well.